# Move to a directory in the directory stack in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

In **bash** one can "rotate" the directory stack with `pushd` to change the current directory:

```bash
rego@tw:~/bin> dirs
~/bin ~/devel ~

rego@tw:~/bin> pushd
~/devel ~/bin ~

rego@tw:~/devel> pushd +2
~ ~/devel ~/bin
```

In **Powershell** I create a directory stack:

```
PS C:\> pushd C:/Users
PS C:\Users> pushd C:/Windows
PS C:\Windows> Get-Location -Stack

Path
----
C:\Users
C:\
```

Now how can I move to a directory in the stack, or swap the top two directories?

I tried using `popd`, which returns to the top directory in the stack, but then if I just want to move to a directory I have to pop all the ones above it.

Comment: Use CD path or CD .\..

Comment: As of v7.3.x, PowerShell lacks many directory-stack management features that Bash has. [GitHub issue #19775](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19775) is a request to close this feature gap. It also contains a prototype implementation that may do what you want.